# Create Custom AlertDialog Builder and Change Font of Title & Message

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, typeface

I have created a  Custom **AlertDialog Builder** and I need to change font of title and message in alertdialog but am not able to achieve this by following way.

CustomAlertDialogBuilder.java :

```
public class CustomAlertDialogBuilder extends AlertDialog.Builder {

    public CustomAlertDialogBuilder(Context context) {
        super(context);
        TextView title = (TextView) create().getWindow().findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
        TextView message = (TextView) create().getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.message);

        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/my_font.ttf");
        title.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        message.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    }
}
```

infact the TextView's are null. How do I define TextViews? I'm a beginner, Please help me to change font of alertdialog with create custom alertdialog.

Answer (score 0):

I use custom dialogs quite often so I use `DialogFragment`. Note this dialog has an "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons. You can remove the buttons if you do not need them.

You need to create an XML Layout for the Custom `DialogFragment` "fragment_submit_cancel_dialog". The ability to create your own design gives you a great deal of flexibility in the appearance of your dialog.

In the Activity you call the `DialogFragment` you will need to add this:

```
implements  OkCancelDialogFragment.OkCancelDialogListener{
```

and add the listener method:

```
@Override
public void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit) {
    if(submit){
        // Do what you need here
    }
}
```

Call the `DialogFragment` like this:

```
private void startOkDialog(){
    String title = "What ever you want as a Title";
    String mess = "Your Message!";
    OkCancelDialogFragment dialog = OkCancelDialogFragment.newInstance(title, mess);
    show(getFragmentManager(), "OkDialogFragment");
}
```

Now the code for the Custom Dialog Fragment:

```
public class OkCancelDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    Context context = null;

    private String title;
    private String message;
    private boolean submitData = false;

    private OkCancelDialogListener mListener;

    public OkCancelDialogFragment() {
    }

    public static OkCancelDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        OkCancelDialogFragment fragment = new OkCancelDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
            message = getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveIntsanceState){

        context = getActivity();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_submit_cancel_dialog, null, false);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        final TextView messView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        titleView.setText(title);
        messView.setText(message);

        builder.setView(rootView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_Ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        submitData = true;
                        //The onDetach will call the Listener! Just in case the user taps the back button
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        submitData = false;
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OkCancelDialogListener {
        void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit);
    }

}
```